# Working with Tortoise SVN plugins in C#

Tags: c#, plugins, tortoisesvn

I am creating a new plugin in C# for TSVN. I downloaded the C# example from http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/ .

I run the example and follow the steps mentioned here 
http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/issue-tracker-plugins.txt

But, as soon as I set up my plugin in TSVN , TSVN throws the following error at me.
"The Issue Tracker provider could not be created. Please Check that it is installed correctly."

Somebody knows the reason why?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should build it in debug and see what is happening at initialization

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't follow the .txt file first.  Instead:

1. Open the C# solution http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/ExampleCsPlugin/ExampleCsPlugin.sln
2. Rebuild it
3. Edit the ExampleCsPlugin.reg file and change the file:// paths to point to where your .dll was built (should be ...\ExampleCsPlugin\bin\Debug in your working copy).
4. Double click the .reg file from explorer (open it in regedit.exe)

You should be able to see the plugin in TortiseSVN's settings dialog when you click the "add..." button.  Once you've gotten this far start modifying things and creating a new project as the .txt instructs.